# Android L Preview After device unlock Contacts app open

Tags: applications

In My Nexus 5 after I unlock my device ervery time contacts/people app is open up automatically. Do I Need to change any settings??

Comment: Do you have a secure lock screen? How is it being opened automatically?

Comment: I do not have a secure lock screen with face unlock or pattern or pin. If I unlock phone then then on swipe of lock screen directly contacts app opens up.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that you are swiping sideways? 
the contacts app is on the left of the lockscreen, the phone app on the right, and to unlock you must swipe up

Answer (score 1):

I've found this is a feature

Swipe up = unlock normally

Swipe down = notifications

Swipe right = contacts

Swipe left = camera